# How to limit characters of a subject plain text field of MediaWiki ContactPage extension?

Tags: php, html, parsing, external, mediawiki

In MediaWiki 1.33.0 I have a [ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage) contact form with HTMLForm default template.
This contact form contains a *subject* plain text field with the HTML *name attribute* of `wpSubject`.

### My problem

For some reason `$wgContactConfig['default'] = array()` which contains the HTMLForm default template, doesn't include the *subject* plain text field **code**.

This prevents me from doing what I desire, which is to limit the amount of characters of that *subject* plain text field with PHP.

### What I have tried

Given the form is parsed from an [HTMLForm](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HTMLForm) template engine, I searched for a solution in *HTMLForm* manual and found only the `min` and `max` values,
but these values seems to me to limit integer number values and not a field's character amount.

### My question

How to limit characters of a *subject* plain text field of MediaWiki ContactPage extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd use the `validation-callback` option for this, but there isn't really any way to modify the configuration of predefined fields in ContactPage, as far as I can see from [the code](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-ContactPage/blob/1f039082d5704ba8f19779d7ee9d64e1fb173e46/includes/SpecialContact.php#L153-L190).

Comment: I feel I should say, utilization of HTMLForm seems to me, as a non PHP programmer, a bit odd; it seems to me to increase complexity rather than decreasing it; for example, some fields are included but aren't others.

Comment: Yeah, it would be more reasonable to expose the whole form descriptor for customization, or at least do `array_merge` instead of `+`. Feel free to file a bug / write a patch :)